# Read numbers with different length from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file called `data` contains the following lines:

```
0.487856 0.487856 0.024289 1.000000
0.500000 0.500000 0.487856 0.487856 0.024289
0.024289 0.487856 0.487856 0.487856 0.487856 0.024289
0.024289 0.487856 0.487856 0.500000 0.500000
1.000000 0.024289 0.487856 0.487856
```

I would like to read it to python and store the data in a dictionary where the key is the line number and the values are the entires in each line as

```
d = { '0': [0.487856, 0.487856, 0.024289, 1.000000], '1': [ 0.500000, 0.500000, 0.487856, 0.487856, 0.024289], ..., '4': [1.000000, 0.024289, 0.487856, 0.487856]}
```

so that,

```
d['0'] = [0.487856, 0.487856, 0.024289, 1.000000]
len(d['0']) = 4
```

I tried to do it like this

```
d={}
infile = open('data', 'r')
line_num = 1
for line in infile:
    d[line_num] = line
    line_num += 1

infile.close()
```

I got:

```
d
{1: '0.487856 0.487856 0.024289 1.000000\n', 2: '0.500000 0.500000 0.487856 0.487856 0.024289\n', 3: '0.024289 0.487856 0.487856 0.487856 0.487856 0.024289\n', 4: '0.024289 0.487856 0.487856 0.500000 0.500000\n', 5: '1.000000 0.024289 0.487856 0.487856\n'}
```

First, I couldn't number the keys starting from `0`, when the counter started from `0`, the resulted dictionary contains only one key which is `0` as:

```
d
{0: '1.000000 0.024289 0.487856 0.487856\n'}
```

Also, although `d['0'] = [0.487856, 0.487856, 0.024289, 1.000000]` but `len(d['0']) = 36` which means that all entires for this key represent one value and I didn't read them as separate values.

How can I fix this code and write it in an efficient way (because I have huge data)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("data") as infile:
    d = {str(index): [float(n) for n in line.split()] for index, line in enumerate(infile)}
```

Comment: This is probably the wrong solution to your actual problem though. If you want to access data based on a zero indexed integer key, just read your file into a list... better yet, do whatever processing you want to do on the dictionary as you're reading the list. You might want to ask a more specific question http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Boris Thanks for your help. In fact it doesn't matter if the keys started from 0 or 1 but I was wondering why it didn't produce the required dictionary in my case when the counter started from 0 while did it when it was 1.
Does it affect your solution?

Comment: I think you're expecting python to notice that your file contains some numbers on each line on interpret them that way. It's not that smart. When it reads a file it returns the actual letters/characters in a list of lines that you then have to `split` on space characters and parse the resulting groups of characters into `float`. I would recommend reading all the way through https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial

Comment: No it doesn't effect the solution. The numbers are provided by `enumerate` and have no effect on reading or parsing the lines of the file. You could just as well do `enumerate(infile, start=55)` and it would work just the same but the dictionary keys would start at 55.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> d={}
> infile = open('data', 'r')
> line_num = 1
> for line in infile:
>     d[line_num] = line
>     line_num += 1
> ```

is close I think,

This should better get you what you want

```
d={}
infile = open('data', 'r')
line_num = 1
for line in infile:
    d[line_num] = line.strip().split()
    line_num += 1

infile.close()
```